# making sense of calculations in the proof that the image of an embedding is an embedded submanifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, inverse-function-theorem

I am having trouble understanding the proof of

**Theorem** If $F : M \to N$ is an embedding, then $F (M)$ is an embedded
submanifold of $N$

Proof. Let $p \in M$. Since $F$ is an immersion, by Theorem 1 (see below) there are charts $(U,\varphi)$ around $p$ and $(V,\psi )$ around $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$ and for all
$x \in \varphi(U)$,
$\psi\circ F \circ \varphi^{−1}(x) = (x; 0_{n−m})\tag{4}$

By applying translations we can assume that $\varphi(p) = 0_m$ and $\psi(F(p)) = 0_n$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ so that

$B_{\varepsilon}(0_m) \subseteq \varphi(U)$ and $B_{\varepsilon}(0_n) \subseteq \psi(V )$

Then $B_{\varepsilon}(0_m) \times \{0_{n-m}\} \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(0_n) \subseteq \psi(V)\tag{5}$

Because $F:M\to F(M) $is a homeomorphism, then $F(\varphi^{−1}(B_{\varepsilon}(0_m))) \subseteq F(M)$ open in the subspace topology. So there is an open subset $W \subseteq N$ such that

$F(\varphi^{−1}(B_{\varepsilon}(0_m))) =W\cap F(M) \tag{ 6}$

And because of (4),

$\psi(W\cap F(M)) = (\psi\circ F \circ \varphi^{−1})(B_{\varepsilon}(0_m))) \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(0_m) \times \{0_{n-m}\}\tag{ 7}$

Let $\tilde {W}=W \cap \psi^{-1}(B_{\varepsilon}(0_n))$

So $(\tilde {W}, \psi|_{\tilde W}) $ is a chart around $F(p)$ with

$\psi|_{\tilde {W}}(\tilde{W} \cap F(M)) $

$= \psi|_{\tilde{W}}( W \cap \psi^{-1}(B_{\varepsilon}(0_n)) \cap F(M))$
$=\psi (W \cap F(M)) \tag{8}$
$=B_{\varepsilon}(0_m)\times \{0_{n-m}\}\tag{9}$
$=\psi|_{\tilde {W}}(\tilde {W})\cap (\Bbb R^{m}\times\{0_{n-m}\})\tag{10}$

**1)Is there is a typo in (7)?** I think it should be "$=$" instead of "$\subseteq$"
because then I think that's what it's being used to go from (8) to (9).

2)**I can't figure out what is going on in the last chain of equalities**.The preceding expressions should be used somehow , but it's not clear how. How does $\psi^{-1}(B_{\varepsilon}(0_n))$ dissapear in (8)? How do I get (9)? and how do I go from there to (10)?

---

The definition of embedded submanifolds that is being used in this last part is:

DEF Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $m$, and $S ⊂ M$. Then
$S$ is an embedded submanifold of dimension $k$ if for every $p \in S $ there is a chart  $(U, \varphi)$ of $M$ around $p$ is such that
$\varphi(U \cap S) = (\Bbb R^k \times \{0_{m-k}\}) \cap \varphi(U)$

and at the beginning of the proof a particular case of the rank theorem used:

Theorem 1 (Rank theorem for injective differential). Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold  of dimension $m$, and that $N$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n$. Suppose $F : M \to N$ is smooth. Let $p \in M$. If $dF_p$ is injective, then there are charts $(U, \varphi)$ of M around p and $(V,\psi )$ of N around $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$
and for all $x \in\varphi(U)$, and

$\psi\circ F \circ \varphi^{−1}(x) = (x, 0_{n−m})$